# explicitly tell into what language to translate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have as usual my translation files in locales.

Now I have an invitation mail in various languages.

I want the user to select in what language the mail should be sent, because it's not about the language of the operating user, it's about the language the mail receiver should read.

Is there a way to tell rails explicitly what language to pick, like `t(:my_string, :en)`?

The goal is, to have it temporary translated for only one single call of `t`.

This is what I need, to tell within the `t()` command, what language is to be used.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to pass `:locale` option to `t` method:

```
  t :my_string, locale: :de
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you will explicitly need to set proper language to I18n.
You can use: `I18n.locale = :en` to set language you need. 
Also look here: [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: I know this, but this is not the answer on my question. I want temporary to select from a locale file, in pseudo code like `t(:my_sentence, :en)` to translate `:my_sentence` only once to `:en`

Comment: You cannot make translation like that, `t` or `l` methods watch for `I18n.locale` value, so you will need to explicitly set it. Or you can override `t` method :)

Comment: at least not, right, but at this moment I was sure there will be the solution I demanded *downvote-reverted* - sorry, downvote was already locked

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `I18n` backend which take the locale as first argument:

`I18n.backend.translate(:en, :my_string)`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to temporarily change locale:
`I18n.with_locale(:*your_locale*)` serves the purpose.

for further readings, https://translation.io/blog/rails-i18n-with-locale

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, you need to have locale information for the receiver. Once you have that, you can pass it to `I18n.t` method in your rails code.

```rb
preferred_locale = `Receiver.preferred_locale_name` || I18n.default_locale

I18n.t('sample-string', locale: preferred_locale)
```